# Photo shared with checkin

Tags: foursquare

I'm using the checkins/CHECKIN_ID API to retrieve data about a specific checkin. There isn't the photo object even if it should be always present, if the user has taken it... Is it a current issue or am I in error?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the check-in you are inspecting has a photo? If the creator of the check-in has not taken a photo, it will not be present in the response. Also, make sure that the API request is being made from a user account that is able to see the check-in.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it with our checkins and I'm sure that the checkin has a photo also because I see the photo in the venue.
Then, the request is sent from an app the user has previously connected with his account. I get the whole checkin object (venue, shout, score,...) but not the photo, not the photo's ID...

Comment: If you see the photo at the venue, it is possible that the photo is associated with another check-in. You should look at the checkin detail page in your browser (at http://foursquare.com/user/USER_ID/checkin/CHECKIN_ID), and see if you can see the photo there.

Comment: Thx phhayes. I'll do more investigation and keep you informed.